# Visual Studio Filenames

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, filepath

I think this is a simple question but I can't figure out how to do it. I have a C++ project that I am compiling and running on Windows but I am running into an issue with the NiTE2 library I am using. When NiTE2 calls a specific function required for setup it searches for an "s.dat" file located at "./NiTE2/s.dat". The problem is when I run it in the Visual Studio environment it tries to search the path ".\NiTE2/s.dat". That's not a typo it mixes the slashes. The program understandably can't find the necessary file. However when I run my program under Git Bash it executes just fine.

Using Git Bash works but it's making debugging extremely difficult, does anyone know how or if it is possible to get the Visual Studio run-time environment to use forward slashes instead of Windows default backslashes for the path? The path that defines where to find "s.dat" is buried in proprietary code that I can't edit so that solution is out.

Side Note: I'm running Windows 10 if that helps in anyway. I'm trying to get bash debugging with VSCode working but that's also an uphill battle at the moment.

Comment: Mixing slashes works just fine on Windows.  Not being able to find a file is of course excessively common, the default working directory is the worst possible global variable.  Just don't use relative paths, create a full path from the program's install directory so it works no matter where you put it and don't depend on config at all.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree with you that relative pathing is a poor idea I always use absolute paths in my code but like I mentioned I am unable to modify that portion of the code. That is buried inside the NiTE2 library, of which I only have the final compiled version. If mixing slashes is acceptable on Windows any other ideas why it's complaining about not finding the file in the visual studio environment but does just fine in git bash and command prompt?

Comment: Well, just feed the beast and give it what it wants to eat.  Explicitly set the working directory in your code so you know it is always correct.  Use SetCurrentDirectory() or `_chdir()`.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't know about that function, thanks! That feels so wrong but it fixed my problem and I can successfully debug now.

Comment: You can also tell Visual Studio by the project settings what directory should be the current directory when a program is run from the IDE: `Configuration Properties | Debugging | Working Directory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think visual studio is choosing an unexpected working directory, and if you edit the working directory, it should work just fine.

To solve this problem, I use the system internals [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) tool.  When I run my application, the full path of the files which are attempted, are shown.

Visual Studio starts an application in a strange working directory (the location of the source), and this can be a major cause for lost files, when running in the debugger.

You can change the debuggers starting directory by going to the .exe location in the solution explorer, right clicking to edit the properties, and choosing the "Debugging" configuration property.

Here you can set the command Arguments - sent as text into the program, and the Working Directory.

Windows has 2 path parsers.   The native NT path parser does not accept /, but there is a DOS parser which may be activated.  The DOS parser differs by :-

- Not caring about '\' or '/'
- Allowing relative searching `c:\program files\myApp\..\yourapp\prog.exe`
- Not caring about consecutive '\' or '//'
- There are some strange rules about spaces at the end of the file. (DOS parser can't open such).

The DOS parser can be disabled when opening a file with '\?' prepended to the path and using the unicode variant of the function.

```
wfopen( L"\\\\?\\c:\\program files\\yourapp\\prog.exe", L"rb" );
```

So in normal operation, '\' and '/' are equivalent, except if the DOS parser is disabled.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I knew it was something simple I was missing but I didn't know how to make Visual Studio use the location of the .exe file. Thanks @mksteve for the well written breakdown of how it handles file path parsing.